# My Docker container gives me an ImportError: Cannot import name 'Markup' from Jinja2

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to get an app running using a Dockerfile. I've created the image, and the container however I get an error message when I try to run the app. The message in the docker dashboard says Exited(1) which means it does not seem to connect. The ImportError message I get is down below. How can I get this up and running?

Here are the contents of the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-alpine
LABEL maintainer="TEMP_NAME"
COPY . /git_rank
WORKDIR /git_rank
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python server.py
```

Here is the command that I ran to get the docker app runing:

```
docker run -i -t -d -p 9000:9000 --name name_of_app name_of_app
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/git_rank/server.py", line 6, in <module>

    from flask import Flask, abort, Response

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

    from jinja2 import Markup, escape

ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation for Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/?highlight=markup#version-3-0-1) shows that Markup is now within the `jinja2.utils.markupsafe` module! You can access it like so:

```
from jinja2.utils import markupsafe 
markupsafe.Markup()

Markup('')
```